# New columns with incremental numbers that initial based on a diffrent column value (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a column with incremental numbers for rows with the same value in a defined row;

e.g. if I would have this df

```
df=pd.DataFrame([['a','b'],['a','c'],['c','b']])
```

and I want incremental numbers for the first column. It should look like this

```
df=pd.DataFrame([['a','b',1],['a','c',2],['c','b',1]])
```

I found sql solutions but I'm working with ipython/pandas. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), for name of new column use `length` of original `columns`:

```
print (len(df.columns))
2

df[len(df.columns)] = df.groupby(0).cumcount() + 1
print (df)
   0  1  2
0  a  b  1
1  a  c  2
2  c  b  1
```

Comment: Glad can help, nice day!